# Slight white space between inline elements?

Tags: html, css

I know that when using inline-block elements you get unwanted white space.

But why in this example have these two inline link elements got a slight space between them?

You can see they are on two lines and if I put them side by side and remove the space in my text editor the space is then gone, but surely it should ignore the space in my text editor?

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

This has space between the links.

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a><a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

This doesn't.

Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/hfgjwj55/

Comment: Does this only happen in the jsfiddle? or also in your own project. jsfiddles places the code in an iframe which could cause some weird issues

Comment: Hi Robbin, no this happens on my local aswell.

Answer (score 3):

When you give a new line between two elements, one space will be added between them as below.

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

The above and the below are same,

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

If you haven't given any white space or new line then there won't be any space between elements.

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a><a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

Even if you provide two space between the elements as below, it will be rendered with only one space.

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

So,if you need more than one space you have to use `&nbsp;` as below.

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Cheers. I like your explanation.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine Cool :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's different options to avoid white-space of being displayed, in your example you could:

- display the a-tags as inline-block and float them left https://jsfiddle.net/hfgjwj55/3/

  ```
  a {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left; 
  }
  ```
- set font-size on the wrapper (in this case the body) 0 and the font-size of the a-tags to e.g. 16px
  https://jsfiddle.net/hfgjwj55/2/

  ```
  body {
      font-size: 0;
  }

  a {
      font-size: 16px;
  }
  ```
- put html comments between the elements

Answer (score 2):

This has been a problem for me a lot of times aswell.

I usually always solve it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/g7h0fbyn/

```
   <a href="#">link 1</a><!--
--><a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

There already is a Question to this on stackoverflow, with a really nice answer, you should check it out: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: That's for inline block elements, I meant inline elements.

Comment: This applys to both inline and inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you place any number of blank spaces in HTML code it will be converted to one blank space.

1.

```
    <body>
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </body
```

New line will be adding one space between two elements. so either its one space or multiple it would be considered one white space between two elements.

2.

```
<body>
   <a href="#">link 1</a>   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body>`
```

both above case will have one space between it. while below code will not have any space in between

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a><a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body
```

if you want multiple spaces use `&nbsp;` as follow:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Link 2</a>
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't see the difference in which whitespace is wanted and which isn't; all whitespace is collapsed into a single space character (unless otherwise specified by `pre` and the like).

Other than removing the whitespace in your source code, one possible (though kind of tricky) solution is to globaly set `font-size` to 0 globally and resetting it for particular elements.

Another way is to comment out the whitespace like this:

```
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

Though that may be a bit messy.

There are ways to avoid this problem altogether, like using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), but that's probably overkill for your example.

Answer (score -1):

You can add margin left to remove white space.

```
a{
margin-left:-4px;
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't format it like this.

Comment: This won't work reliably for different fonts and font sizes.